# Running Program from Folder File

Tags: python, terminal

I find my created python file in the windows folder. I double click to run where I only get the window. I enter the information and never see the output result. The window closes too fast. What is a good way to stop this or pause the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `input("Please plress Enter to exit")` . This will display the line as well as close when enter is pressed.
I hope it helps

Comment: Excellent. This worked great! Something so simple causing such great headaches..

Comment: @jjg447 If it worked then accept the answer by pressing button at the left :)